Fréchet Differentiability of a series of norms
I am currently trying to understand the proof of Theorem 9.14 from "Banach Space Theory",Fabian M. et al, which characterizes super-reflexivity. The theorem affirms the following:
Let $X$ be a Banach space. The following statements are equivalent:

$X$ is superreflexive
$X$ admits an equivalent uniformly convex norm
$X$ admits an equivalent uniformly Fréchet differentiable norm
$X$ admits an equivalent norm which is uniformly convex and uniformly Fréchet
differentiable.

One of the steps of the proof is to show that 2 and 3 imply 4. So, using two equivalent norms, one uniformly convex and the other uniformly Fréchet differentiable, they construct a new norm that is uniformly convex and uniformly Fréchet differentiable, denoted by $\rvert\rvert\rvert\cdot\lvert\lvert\lvert$ and defined as $\rvert\rvert\rvert x\lvert\lvert\lvert^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\|x\|_n^2}{2^n}$.
Then, they say that since the derivative of $\lVert\cdot\rVert^2_n$ is bounded in bounded sets for all $n\geq1$, $\lvert\lvert\lvert\cdot\rvert\rvert\rvert$ (although in the book they write $\lVert\cdot\rVert$, which I believe is a mistake) is uniformly Fréchet differentiable.
I've been thinking about this, and even though I see it as a pretty natural conclusion, I have not being able to prove it. I have tried using Weierstrass M-test but you can not bound the sums by something not depending on n.
Besides, I've found this result that states that (skipping details) the series of Fréchet differentiable functions is Fréchet differentiable and the series of derivatives is the derivative of the series, but they do not say nothing about uniformity, so maybe it is lost using this result.
Thank you in advance for reading and I hope someone can help me. I would really appreciate it!
See you!

How is each $||\bullet||_n$ built from the equivalent norms?

$\lVert\cdot\rVert_n$ is built as follows. You have $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ and $\lVert\cdot\rVert_0$ in $X$ which are equivalent norms that are uniformly convex and uniformly Fréchet differentiable, respectively. You then send them to the dual space. Now you hace the norms $\lVert\cdot\rVert*$ and $\lVert\cdot\rVert_0*$, which are uniformly Fréchet differentiable and uniformly convex, respectively, by duality of these two concepts. 1/2

Then you construct $\lVert\cdot\rVert^_n=\lVert\cdot\rVert^+\frac{1}{n}\lVert\cdot\rVert_0^$ on $X^$, that is well defined because of the equivalence of the norms. $\lVert\cdot\rVert_n$ is then its predual norm. 2/2
